# replace text with formula in calculate

Tags: calculated-column

How can I replace ";" in a text like this with " AND " ?

example text: "abc;cde;efg;ijk"
the result should be like this: "abc AND cde AND efg AND ijk"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=REPLACE([YourColumnname],FIND(";",[YourColumnname]),1," AND ")
```

This should get you going in the right direction. [Calculated Field Formulas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

[image]

The column "NewColumn1" is using the exact formula as above, and was created from the SharePoint Designer. I Don't know why it did not work from the UI. I'm using the default language pack.

**EDIT** For sites using english as a regional setting "," work's, but any regional setting need to use ";" instead.

[REPLACE function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/replace-function-HA001161055.aspx)

Comment: thanks. I did exactly the same bit I got this ERROR: The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported.    [mycolumn] type is a single line of text. this is the code at the moment: =REPLACE([mycolumn],FIND(";",[mycolumn]),1," AND ")

Comment: You should replace the "mycolumn" with the name of your textcolumn.

Comment: of course:D mycolumn is the name of my column.the default language of our site is German. maybe I should write the German equivalent of REPLACE and SEARCH. does it make sens? 

also in this document I couldn't find anything about REPLACE code in the formula. isn't it strange?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: I just tried lots of functions and not a single one of the microsoft standard did work. However when i entered them in sharepoint designer the one above did work out.