# Document name with one (1) period in the middle

Tags: 2010, workflow, document-library

Currently, I have a document library that holds personnel files and a workflow that is triggered on change.  The workflow fires after the appropriate fields are filled out and those fields are:

- Employee Name (People Picker)
- Year
- Type of Document

The issue that I have run into is that whenever an employee has a middle initial and period after, the file name does not update.  Example would be John A. Doe does not copy to the file name field but John A Doe does.  Here is a screen shot of my workflow:

[image]

The first update item is where the employee name is converted to plain text (string).

Is there a way to correct this with a work around either within the workflow or within a field?

The file name should look like:

```
John A Doe_2017_Type of Document
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Some of this depends on where you're having an issue and what you're trying to do, but it's possible that the value needs to be encoded.

You can use a 'Replace substring in string' action (Utility Actions) to replace that period with the encoded URL equivalent (%2E). Then you can use that encoded value to interact with a file with a period. You could also just replace periods with empty characters ("") when it goes to set the name.

Comment: Where is 'replace substring in string' accessible from?

Comment: Under the Action button in the workflow designer in SharePoint Designer 2013. You can add it as a step, replace the string as you need it into a variable and work with it from there in a subsequent step.

Comment: I am working with 2010 WFs, is there another way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried using the 'Name (for use in forms)' field instead of the 'Name' field?

Comment: Yes, I am using Name (for use in forms)

Comment: If you've tried the different Name/Title fields (and those values aren't correct for you), you can't use 2013 workflows (which have the replace function) and you can't make it work and you can't control the input, you'll have to use a calculated column (https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93770/replace-text-with-formula-in-calculate). If you have issues beyond that, you're going to need to get the error log and find out what specifically is causing it to choke.

Comment: I have ended up using a calculated column to extract a portion of the name and inserted that into my file name extension.  Thank you.