# Updating a column using choices from other lists

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list, workflow, designer

I have a list A with a choice column (Choice 1,2,3). And a list B with the same choices column B.

I have also a third list, List C with column A and B which are updated through workflow from the lists A and B respectively.

My problem is: If I go to List A and Choose the choices 1 and 2 which update the column A in list C. And from List B I choose choice 1 which updates the column B in list C.

How could a column in List C be updated containing only choice 2 (choices from column A minus column B)?.

The choices I have are not numbers are text choices.

Using SharePoint 2013 Site and SharePoint Designer workflow 2010.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As you are using SharePoint designer workflow 2010, things will become a bit troublesome for 2010 workflow does not have the replace substring in string action. With this action, simply replace the choices from B column with white space in A column and the job is done.

You can get the choice text value in Designer with a lookup,remember to return filed as choices, comma delimited.

[image]

Then you will need two dummy columns to hold the text value of A and B column, use a workflow to update Dummy A and Dummy B to get the text value. Make the C column to be a calculated column and use the Replace, Find and len function to find the index of choice in B and replace it with white space. A similar sample:[replace text with formula in calculate](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93770/replace-text-with-formula-in-calculate)

Comment: thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! :)

Comment: @Nemesis, Glad to be help. You can mark the reply as answer if that solves your issue.